# gerar um arquivo json com java

Tags: java, json

> Insertion iterativo: 7841910ns - 7ms
>
> Selection iterativo: 2677762ns - 2ms
>
> Merge iterativo: 708154ns - 0ms

Esse algoritmo foi feito em **Java**, no console do java é impresso vários valores, sendo:

- nome do algoritmo de busca
- tempo em ns pra rodar o algoritmo
- esse tempo em ns transformado em ms.

tem algum jeito de transformar esses dados em uma arquivo json (gerar um arquivo usando java) pra eu ler usando um script em javascript?
a ideia era abrir esse arquivo .json no javascript ou vice-versa e transforma-lo em uma tabela (eu não sei fazer interface em java, então achei mais fácil fazer isso (em gerar o arquivo json em uma tabela em html)).

Answer (score 8):

Sim, usando a biblioteca [json-simple,](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) por exemplo:

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

public class JsonExample {
     public static void main(String[] args) {

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

    for (Object algoritmo : algoritmos){
        JSONArray tempos = new JSONArray();
        tempos.add(algoritmo.tempo_ms);
        tempos.add(algoritmo.tempo_ns);

        obj.put(algoritmo.nome, tempos);
    }
    try {

        FileWriter file = new FileWriter("/caminho/do/arquivo");
        file.write(obj.toJSONString());
        file.flush();
        file.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     }
}
```

Assim será gerada a seguinte estrutura JSON:

```
{
     "Insertion iterativo": ["7841910ns", "7ms"],
     "Selection iterativo": ["2677762ns", "2ms"],
     "Merge iterativo": ["708154ns", "0ms"]
}
```

Há muitas outras bibliotecas para se trabalhar com JSON em Java, como pode ser visto em [json.org.](http://www.json.org)

Answer (score 2):

Existe uma biblioteca da google chamada [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list?can=1&q=)
 muito simples de usar. Faça o download dela, coloca no seu projeto e use o seguinte código.

```
//Instancia objeto responsável por manipular JSON
Gson gson = new Gson();

//Transformar objeto em JSON
String json = gson.toJson(meuObjeto);

//Transformar JSON em Objeto
meuObjeto = gson.fromJson(json, MeuObjeto.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar o [JsonObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html) do Java EE 7:

```
String nome = "Joao";
Integer idade = 30;

JsonObject json = Json.createObjectBuilder()
                        .add("nome", nome)
                        .add("idade", idade)
                        .build();

String jsonString = json.toString();
```