# Como usar JSON em Java

Tags: java, json

Olá, eu queria saber como usar arquivos JSON, na linguagem Java, pois eu preciso usar eles como banco de dados. Eu queria saber, apenas, como ler e escrever, apenas isso.

Comment: Não tinha achado essa pergunta, obrigado

Comment: Como eu posso realizar a leitura do arquivo? ali não explica muito bem

Comment: [Essa leitura aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/60748/38938) explica como fazer a "leitura" do arquivo, GSON é uma bibliteca muito simples, e esse exemplo ja te explica muito sobre. Se quiser algo mais aprofundado como ele funciona tem esse [artigo aqui](http://www.aquiejava.com/2012/11/gson-converta-json-em-objeto-java-de-forma-simples.html) Ele explica de uma forma bem prática como funciona tudo.